# s3 upload split output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an interesting case. I need to upload tar file, splitted by linux `split` directly to S3 bucket. I have no enough disk space and time for creating one big .tar file and it's next splitting, so I'm trying to use pipelines:

`tar -cvf - example-file.log | split -b 10k -d - "tarpart-" | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/`

Unfortunately, I have no parts of my file in S3, just only:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
2019-02-14 13:07:38          0 -
```

I'm not sure if there a way to upload multiple files with undefined names, but maybe someone had the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution:

```
# tar -cvf - install.post.log | split -d -b 4k -a 4 - splitted_ --filter='aws s3 cp - s3://testb/$FILE'
install.post.log
# aws s3 ls s3://testb
2019-02-14 14:49:38      40960 -
2019-02-14 14:55:09       4096 splitted_0000
2019-02-14 14:55:10       4096 splitted_0001
2019-02-14 14:55:11       4096 splitted_0002
2019-02-14 14:55:11       4096 splitted_0003
2019-02-14 14:55:12       4096 splitted_0004
2019-02-14 14:55:13       4096 splitted_0005
2019-02-14 14:55:13       4096 splitted_0006
2019-02-14 14:55:14       4096 splitted_0007
2019-02-14 14:55:14       4096 splitted_0008
2019-02-14 14:55:15       4096 splitted_0009
```